# AWS flagged my subnet as invalid although it looks to be within the VPC CIDR block

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, tcpip

My VPC CIDR block is `10.0.0.0/16`
As I understand it, this should support 256 (effectively 254) subnets with 65534 hosts per subnet.

When I tried to create one subnet `10.8.0.0/24` and associate it with the VPC, I received this error:

```
Error creating subnet: 
  InvalidSubnet.Range: The CIDR '10.8.0.0/24' is invalid.
```

An address like `10.8.0.1` belongs to the subnet 10.8.0.0 which looks to be inside `10.0.0.0/16`. Perhaps I am misguided in my understanding. Please explain where I went wrong.

Comment: 10.8.0.1 is within the 10.0.0.0/8 network, the 10.8.0.0/16 network, and the 10.8.0.0/24 network. Another example, 10.8.5.1 is within the 10.0.0.0/8 network, the 10.8.0.0/16 network, and the 10.8.5.0/24 network. CIDR is a bit funky, I've been working with it for a while and I'm not even 100% sure these examples are correct, so I run everything important past a network engineer.

Comment: @Tim thanks for offering an explanation. When I get over the Class A, B and C conventions of the past; CIDR makes more sense.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Nope, `10.8.0.0/24` doesn't fall into `10.0.0.0/16`. AWS is correct, sorry :)

In your `10.0.0.0/16` you can create subnets between `10.0.0.0/24` to `10.0.255.0/24`, e.g. `10.0.8.0/24` would work.

---

Let's say we've got CIDR address `10.20.30.40` - that can fall for example into these subnets:

- `10.0.0.0/8` - **/8** means only the first byte (10.) in the address is the network address.
- `10.20.0.0/16` - **/16** means the first two bytes (10.20.) are network.
- `10.20.30.0/24` - **/24** means the first three bytes (10.20.30.) are network.
- `10.20.30.40/32` - **/32** covers the whole address (10.20.30.40) and sometimes this notation is used to explicitly say it's a host address. AWS uses that a lot.

---

Hope that helps :)

Comment: So a /16 means that the first 2 octets is dedicated to the network; and then the user can choose how to partition the 3rd and 4th octets for subnet & hosts. I think I get it now.

Comment: @BonAmi exactly, added some explanation above.